# Google chrome extension browser & page action

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to add a page_action in an extension that already implements browser_action?

I'd like to use the browser_action to display a popup with a list of bookmarks while use the page_action to give the user a way to bookmark the current page and load it in the list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only have one among `app`, `browser_action`, `page_action` and `theme` in your manifest till date. So, you can not have `browser action` and `page action` together.

```
// Pick one (or none)
  "browser_action": {...},
  "page_action": {...},
  "theme": {...},
  "app": {...},
```

## Work Around

Use two different Extensions with [cross extension message communication](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#event-onMessageExternal).

## References

- [Manifest File](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html)