# Why a chrome extension could not have both browser action and page action?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

A single extension can not have both browser action and page action in together in single extension.
[relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14519458/google-chrome-extension-browser-page-action)

What is the logic behind this design choice?

Comment: This question is off-topic, since only Chrome developers can answer with a degree of certainty; anything else would be opinion-based guesswork.

Comment: That said, quote from the docs: _"**Do** use browser actions for features that make sense on most pages.
**Don't** use browser actions for features that make sense for only a few pages. Use page actions instead."_ Add to that single-purpose Webstore policy..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the early days of Chrome extensions, extensions could create multiple page actions. That feature complicated the design, so it was decided that an extension can show at most one button.

> **Issue [24473](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24473): max 1 UI surface per-extension**
>   For extensions beta, we want to start out limiting extensions to a maximum of 
>   1 UI "surface". By "surface", we mean toolstrip, browser action, or page 
>   action.
>
> UI management gets much simpler if there is a concrete relationship between 
>   user-visible features and extensions. And since we now have the bubble, and 
>   will eventually have the options UI, we think that there should be enough 
>   real-estate for people to do interesting things within this limitation.
>
> At the very least, it easier to add than take away, so we would prefer to 
>   start with 1 and relax over time.

I think that this initial design decision remained unchanged, not because of implementation difficulties, but because one of the goals of Chrome is to have minimal UI clutter <sup>[ref](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/extensions/how-the-extension-system-works/extension-manifesto)</sup>. The reason for preventing legacy packaged apps from using these buttons aligns with this goal:

> **Issue [58904](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=58904): Don't allow app launcher to be combined with browser actions or page actions** 
>   We don't want people to grab both just as a way to have increased visibility.